# Which companies will be happy to host a windows executable CGI program on shared hosting?

Tags: windows, cgi, exe, shared-hosting

The rise of the virtual server has been very useful in many ways, but for me it was a pain, as I had a windows executable file that ran as a CGI program.

5-10 years ago this wasn't even an issue, but they are a lot more rare now, and most hosts refuse to take them on shared hosting, instead insisting that you use a virtual private server, which is an order of magnitude more expensive.

I find it a bit of a shame that anything even a little out of the ordinary is now shunted off to VPS, and I also find it strange that windows .exe files are seen as more of a danger than php, perl python etc. If anything, I would say that it is more difficult to exploit an executable, but there you go.

Anyway, the question which I'm self answering is: Which companies will be happy to host a windows executable CGI program on shared hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need a company that has control over their own servers, rather than a reseller, as I don't think any of the "Control Panel" type software programs (such as Plesk) will allow you to do this.

Secondly, you need someone who is flexible enough to do something out of the ordinary.

I used http://ukwindowshostasp.net, they took some persuasion, but in the end were content to host the site on their most expensive shared plan.

I also talked to https://www.freethought-internet.co.uk/, who were super friendly and helpful, and were prepared to set up the CGI program, but weren't prepared to guarantee support for it. This means that it could have stopped working at any time, so I didn't go for it in the end.

The other source of hosts were design companies that host their clients websites having designed them. These companies are more used to flexible bespoke hosting. I spoke to http://www.rocktime.co.uk/ and http://www.alberon.co.uk/, who were both very friendly and helpful and would have hosted the site. The only reason I didn't go with either of them in the end was because I was in a massive rush and a company with 24 hour support got back to me sooner.

One word of warning is that you need to make absolutely sure that your host understands what you mean by a windows executable CGI program. I initially signed up with http://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/, who were happy to take the site, but then after much nagging on my part realised they couldn't and left me in the lurch 2 days before go live.

I hope this helps someone, it took me ages to find a host.

Answer (score 0):

Having used http://ukwindowshostasp.net, I can now say with certainty that you should not use them.

They told me a lot of good things about backups, but it must have all been lies, as they lost my entire website and databases.

I always thought that Hosts were super reliable backup wise, with ISO accreditation and all that, but next time I will be more careful and take more frequent backups myself.